# Cocoa" Compiled "container" file for resources?

Tags: macos, cocoa, bundle

I've noticed that a common trait these days is bundling all of the resources of an app all into one huge file. Basically making disassembly a little more complicated.

Can someone point me to some examples? A few I know of, are "unity3d" compile most of their resources into ".unity3d" files a few games which are written in c and lua apps and games are often all bundles into a data.dat...

I can't seem to find any "generic" objective-c examples...

Any ideas?

Cheers,

A

Answer (score 0):

There's no typical container file format on iOS or Mac OS for any kind of resources.

A standard ZIP archive would probably suit your needs. In case you need more obfuscation you could xor the archive with a simple magic number to make it a little harder to look into the contents.

There are a couple of open source [ZIP libraries](https://github.com/pixelglow/zipzap) to help you with decompressing on the device.

Comment: I wasn't really planning on using zlib. Ideally I was going to have a more bespoke binary and was hoping there were some "best practices" examples.